# Json Export via VBA with wrong end of line encoding

Tags: json, excel, vba

I am trying to export the content of an Excel file to a Json file and need the end of line encoding to be LF instead of CRLF.

My pieced together VBA looks like this:

---

```
Dim fs As Object
Dim jsonfile
Dim rangetoexport As Range
Dim rowcounter As Long
Dim columncounter As Long
Dim linedata As String

' change range here
Set rangetoexport = Range("a1:c8")

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
' change dir here

Set jsonfile = fs.CreateTextFile("X:\Path\" & "FILE.json", True)

linedata = "["
jsonfile.WriteLine linedata
For rowcounter = 2 To rangetoexport.Rows.Count
    linedata = ""
    For columncounter = 1 To rangetoexport.Columns.Count
        linedata = linedata & """" & rangetoexport.Cells(1, columncounter) & """" & ":" & """" & rangetoexport.Cells(rowcounter, columncounter) & """" & ","
    Next
    linedata = Left(linedata, Len(linedata) - 1)
    If rowcounter = rangetoexport.Rows.Count Then
        linedata = "{" & linedata & "}"
    Else
        linedata = "{" & linedata & "},"
    End If

    jsonfile.WriteLine linedata
Next
linedata = "]"
jsonfile.WriteLine linedata
jsonfile.Close

Set fs = Nothing
```

---

I am grateful for any help or hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Write instead of Writeline and append a vbLF

```
jsonfile.Write linedata + vbLF
```